# Anylogic: Assistance in reading a Matrix by each value

Tags: matrix, arraylist, anylogic

currently I am working on an Anylogic Project. I have to simulate and optimize the infrastructure of a supply chain. The Keyfactor for my Simulation is the reduction of the costs transported on the route[Each Kilometer costs a flat rate].

I am struggeling to find the correct methode to let Anylogic read my complete matrix of the size 41 x 17[Snip a part of the matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CURat.png)

I have similar Matrixes with the amount of how much should be delivered and the costs incurred.

I started with importing my Database.
and started creating Dimensions. and thats basically where I started to struggle since I couldnt find any Help on the Examples given in Anylogic.

I simply cant figure out what I have to do that a Parameter can read the whole Arraylist and take the value necessary.

[Logic i try to use. Found in the Help sector, Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atkOe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the database wizard to write the necessary code to extract whatever data you need from a dbase table.

1. Load your xls data into a dbase table
2. Put your cursor into a code field somewhere
3. Click on the [database wizard](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/query-builder.html)
4. Select the data you need

PS: Your data structure is really not in a good format, tbh. It may be a lot easier and more elegant to translate your matrix into a proper relational dbase setup first